# how to handle exception in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, exception

I have an angular application. It has n controllers. I know about $exceptionHandler. This is custom expception handler.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('exceptionHandlingApp')
.config(function($provide) {
$provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$log', '$delegate',
  function($log, $delegate) {
    return function(exception, cause) {
      $log.debug('Default exception handler.');
      $delegate(exception, cause);
    };
  }
]);
});
```

Controller

```
 app.controller('cust1Controller',function($scope,$exceptionHandler)
 {
    //ajax request or anything
 }

 app.controller('cust2Controller',function($scope,$exceptionHandler)
 {
    //ajax request or anything
 }
```

**If any exception occurs in any of the controller, how do I call my custom handler?**

Comment: If you write `throw 'error'` in any controller. does it not go to the custom handler?

Comment: A [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/stever/pypdm/);

Comment: @YinGang, that I know. It is throwing error manually by using throw statement.

Comment: @mJunaidSalaat, if I use throw it throws exception irrespective of the exception occurence, Its like throwing exception manually

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call the handler of an exception. It is called automatically by AngularJS.

To make sure, you can use `debugger` keyword. Let me show an example.

```
angular
    .module("app")
    .config(logExceptionToAPIServer);

function logExceptionToAPIServer($provide) {
    $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", ["$delegate",
        function ($delegate) {
            return function (exception, cause) {
                debugger;
                var http = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http');
                debugger;
                var request = {
                    Message: exception.message,
                    StackTrace: exception.stack
                };
                http.post('yourAddress//', request);
                $delegate(exception, cause);
            };
        }
    ]);
};
```